# Map drive commandline not working in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

Trying to map network drive in C# so though easiest way will be use command line, but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is code I have so far:

```
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C NET USE X: \\INSTALLS\\Deployment /USER:TEST.LOCAL\\Installs pass123 /persistent:yes";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Program compiles fine, just not mapping drive

Comment: Try changing `/C` to `/K` and see if an error message is being shown.

Comment: yes, it's giving error:
System error 1219 has occurred.

    Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more
 than one username, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the
server or shared resource and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your UNC path is wrong, it should be "`\\\\INSTALLS\\Deployment`".

This is because a UNC path is a double backslash "`\\server\share\`" but in a string the backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash becoming "`\\\\server\\share`".

Comment: An easier option is to put `@` before the string as it makes it more readable. For example: `@"\\INSTALLS\Deployment"`